# Why do we say 'soup up'?

Tags: idioms

The phrase 'soup up' is slang that basically means 'to increase the power of' something.  Why do we use 'soup' here?  It seems similar to the phrases 'beef up' and 'pep up', which literally come from the foods beef and pepper, so is it as simple as the fact that it's a variation on those phrases that uses 'soup' as the food?  But why soup?  Is soup considered particularly 'hearty'?

Comment: http://wordoriginsorg.yuku.com/topic/9150/souped-up-suped-up-soup-up-hop-up#.UW5ydKLdd8E https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/souped-up

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=soup

Comment: I know it as "suped-up", from the word "super".  Though you find reference to it online, "souped-up" is much more common - and I don't know why!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OED postulates](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/185166) that *to soup up* may have been influenced by the *super-* prefix, such as is seen in words like *supercharged*:

> [compare quot. 1909 at **soup** *n*. 2c; perhaps influenced by **super-** *prefix*]
>
> Orig. and chiefly with *up*.
>
> To modify (an engine, aircraft, motor vehicle, etc.) to increase its power and efficiency.
>  Also *transf*. and *fig*. *colloq*. (orig. *U.S.*).

Notable citations both early and late include:

> - 1933      C. K. Stewart *Speech Amer. Airman* 92 
>     *Soup Up*, to supercharge.
> - 1939       *Sun* (Baltimore)  3 Aug. 1/6  
>     We have done this without ‘souping up’ our engines, without putting alcohol in our gasoline,..or flying with motors which last only five hours.
> - 1976      K. Benton *Single Monstrous Act* v. 152 
>     He had lovingly souped up the Escort’s engine, and now gave it full throttle.
> - 1979      J. Gardner *Nostradamus Traitor* xxxix. 188  
>    A German car: Opel Kadett, souped, and probably reinforced.

Comment: "Chet Morton was a stout, good-natured boy who loved to eat. Next to that, he enjoyed being with the Hardys and sharing their exciting adventures, although at times, when situations became dangerous, he wished he were somewhere else.  Chet also loved to tinker with machinery and spent long hours on his jalopy, which he called Queen. He was trying to 'soup up' the motor, so that he could have a real 'hot rod.' "  *The Hardy Boys: The House on the Cliff* (1927):

Comment: *Some Experiments in Supercharging in a High-Speed Engine* (p. 219).  Ricardo, Harry R. (The Automobile Engineer, June 1921).  https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Automobile_Engineer/u0gxAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=supercharge&pg=PA223&printsec=frontcover

Answer (score -1):

It may be relevant that a single-valve engine (e.g. the Gnome rotary) was referred to as "monosoupape" in French. So if another valve was added for extra performance, it would have had more "soupapes". This may be a "folk etymology" though.